# Google Cloud IoT - sendCommandToDevice - Service Unavailable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

The `sendCommandToDevice` endpoint seems to be unavailable. I tried sending the command directly from the cloud console on the device page. The notification at the bottom left said, `Command sent to device`, but the inspector on chrome showed a **503** error. Time of error: *17:46:02 UTC Saturday, 27 October 2018*

Request:

`Request URL: https://cloudiot.clients6.google.com/v1/projects/<project-id>/locations/<location-name>/registries/<registry-name>/devices/<device-name>/:sendCommandToDevice?key=<removed>
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 503 
Remote Address: 216.58.196.74:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Payload: {binaryData: "eyJ0ZXN0IjoxfQ==", subfolder: ""}`

Response:

`{
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "The service is currently unavailable.",
    "status": "UNAVAILABLE"
  }
}`

Also, an additional note, `sendCommandToDevice` is not available in the nodejs client library (34.0.0). I had to do API discovery to have the method available.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still receiving the 503? I tested this just now and was able to receive messages successfully.

Also, regarding the the lack of availability of Commands features in the client library, Commands is still in Beta and those methods will be available in the client library once it is fully released.

Comment: Quick update, (sorry I couldnt update the question). Setting `subfolder` to any non-empty string solved the problem _(tested on 28 Oct 2018)_.

I'll test it again soon, and will update.

Comment: @ShantanuThatte can you confirm that with an empty string subfolder, the API call returns UNAVAILABLE? I am not able to reproduce this behavior. Subfolder seems to work for me whether it is unset entirely or set to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to

1. bug in the node library
2. bug in Google's RPC endpoint
3. Lack of testing on Google's part

The problem is that `subfolder` **MUST** be specified, and **MUST** not be an empty string.

As I was using this in a Firebase function, I just use the `firebase` subfolder for any commands being sent that do not have a specific subfolder

```
const request = {
    name: `${registryName}/devices/${deviceId}`,
    binaryData: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(commandMessage)).toString("base64"),
    subfolder: 'firebase'
}
```

Here's functions deps:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^6.4.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.0",
    "googleapis": "^36.0.0",
  },
```